# Use Lambda To Bring up And Tear Down Cluster

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am trying to use a scheduled lambda function to bring up and tear down EMR cluster periodically. I am thinking doing this through CloudFormation, maybe using lambda to start a EMR cluster. All materials I found online is using CloudFormation to start lambda function, but I want the other way around. Does anybody has some ideas, or can point me to some right resources? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a similar use case where i wanted to spin up a cluster based on s3put event, Hive queries load data back to s3 and tear down the cluster.

1. Create a [lambda](https://github.com/vikrame/awslambda/blob/master/createEMRCluster.py) function. You can specify Instance groups, roles and applications etc.
2. Create a bucket and set up Event Notification to send trigger to the lambda function.
   3.Once a s3 object is created in the bucket, a EMR cluster is created. Log on to AWS EMR console to check the progress.

I have above details in a [blog](https://medium.com/@vikrame/next-gen-big-data-with-aws-part-1-e3f79b37251f#.njmv6qv7z) if you are interested